# Unable to re-position a draggable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have a div that I made draggable and am trying to give the user the ability to build some content.   I have it doing most of what I want:

I drag a div from the left toolbar and it lands in the container on the right.  If you don't put it in that container, it gracefully floats back to it's original position.

My issue is:  Once I drop it I can't move it again to put it in another spot within the same container.  How can I fix this?

Note:  I am using jQuery: 1.11 and jQuery UI 1.10

```
     // Draggable elements
        $("#draggable_div").draggable({
            cursor : 'move',
            snap : '#target_builder',
            revert : function(event, ui) {
                $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                    top : 0,
                    left : 0
                };
                return !event;
            },
            stop : function() {
        // do I need to re-initialize it here?  
            }
        });
        $("#target_builder").droppable();


<div>
    <div>
        <div id="draggable_div" style="color: #fefefe; background: #222; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
            <p>Div</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        blank content
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/KbQDQ/

it seems to work her, but not in my real code... hmmm...

Comment: I am using the jQuery UI and not sure how to implement that in jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle with jQuery UI http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/gB8e9/, please update

Comment: i think that 
return !event;
make some error please remove it & try again once

Comment: Not sure what to say; I made a fiddle and it works there (see edit above).

Comment: Figured it out, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

i think that

```
return !event;
```

&

```
stop : function() {
                 $("#draggable_div").draggable( "destroy" );
            }
```

make some error please remove it & try again once

Answer (score 0):

if you remove

```
return !event;
```

the element will stay where you leave it :)
here's the correct code:

```
// Draggable elements
    $("#draggable_div").draggable({
        cursor : 'move',
        snap : '#target_builder',
        revert : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                top : 0,
                left : 0
            };

        },
        stop : function() {
    // do I need to re-initialize it here?  
        }
    });
    $("#target_builder").droppable();
```

Comment: The div DOES stay where I leave it.  The problem is I can't move it again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I am using the Twitter bootstrap framework.  I removed the classes (not shown above) and all works well.